# Re-login and update UI on page refresh using AngularFire

Tags: angular, firebase-authentication, angularfire

I’m starting a project using Angular and firebase auth, I have an auth service and a navbar component, where some items appear depending if the user is logged in or not.

The problem is when I press F5 to reload the page the items in navbar always display like when the user is not logged in and then update only when I navigate to another route

**Auth Service:**

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

    private user: firebase.User;

    constructor(
        public afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
        private http: HttpClient
    ) {
        //Adds an observer for changes to the signed-in user's ID token, which includes sign-in, sign-out, and token refresh events.
        firebase.auth().onIdTokenChanged(u => {
            this.user = u;
        });
    }

    isLoggedIn(): Observable<boolean> {
        return new Observable(o => {
            o.next(this.user != null)
        });
    }

    doLogout() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            if (firebase.auth().currentUser) {
                this.afAuth.auth.signOut();
                resolve();
            }
            else {
                reject();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**NavBar HTML**

```
<mat-nav-list>
  <mat-list-item>
    <a [routerLink]='["/"]' matLine>Home</a>
    <mat-icon matListIcon>home</mat-icon>
  </mat-list-item>
  <mat-list-item *ngIf="!(auth.isLoggedIn()|async)" (click)="openLogin();">
    <span matLine>Login</span>
    <mat-icon matListIcon>person</mat-icon>
  </mat-list-item>
  <mat-list-item *ngIf="auth.isLoggedIn() |async" (click)="logout">
    <span matLine>Logout</span>
    <mat-icon matListIcon>person</mat-icon>
  </mat-list-item>
</mat-nav-list>
```

**NavBar TS**

```
export class NavButtonsComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(
        public dialog: MatDialog,
        private auth: AuthService,
        private router: Router,
        private toaster: ToastrService
    ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    openLogin() {
        this.dialog.open(LoginComponent, {
            minWidth: 300,
            maxWidth: 600
        });
    }

    logout() {
        this.auth.doLogout().then(r => {
            this.toaster.success("You have logged out successfully");
            this.router.navigate(['/']);
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting [authentication state persistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence)?

E.g. you could do something like this in the login method:

```
this.angularFireAuth.auth.setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.SESSION).then(() => {
    return this.angularFireAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
})
```